# Can we say that these statements are equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let f be a function

$∀a,b,c∈ℕ, a<b<c⇒f(a,b,c)=0$

$∀a,b,c∈ℕ, a<b<c$ $∨$ $b<a<c$ $∨$ $b<c<a⇒f(a,b,c)=0$

Are these statements equivalent?

Comment: No. For the second proposition, $b=0, c=1, a=2$ would imply $f(a,b,c) = 0$. This is not true for the first proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we are talking about the set of all the functions $f:\Bbb R^3\mapsto V$ then **no**.

saying $$∀a,b,c∈ℕ, a<b<c\lor b<a<c\lor b<c<a⇒f(a,b,c)=0$$ is equivalent to saying $$∀a,b,c∈ℕ, a<b<c⇒f(a,b,c)=0\land\\∀a,b,c∈ℕ, b<a<c⇒f(a,b,c)=0\land\\∀a,b,c∈ℕ, b<c<a⇒f(a,b,c)=0$$

Comment: What about if the two statements had the same antecedent but one of the statements had multiple consequents with one being the same as the other statement and the rest being separated by ORs?

Comment: If and only if $\bigcup_{k}a_k=a_i$ we can say that $\left(a_1\lor a_2\lor\cdots\lor a_k\implies P\right)=\left(a_i\implies P\right)$